# Как наложить текстуру на объект Terrain в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

На процедурно-сгенерированную поверхность надо наложить текстуру, для начала - хотя бы одну. Однако в уроках по Юнити сплошь рассказывают про накладывание текстур в редакторе, в то время, как мне нужно программное наложение. Попытка сделать это через компонент `Renderer`

```
terrobj.AddComponent<Renderer>();
terrobj.GetComponent<Renderer>().material = material;
```

выдаёт ошибку:

> MissingComponentException: There is no 'Renderer' attached to the
>   "Chunk" game object, but a script is trying to access it. You probably
>   need to add a Renderer to the game object "Chunk". Or your script
>   needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
>   UnityEngine.Renderer.set_material (UnityEngine.Material value) (at
>   <58a34b0a618d424bb5fc18bb9bcdac20>:0) ChunkLoader.Start ()

хотя я, вроде как, явно добавил рендерер. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка, и правильно ли я вообще делаю?

Comment: И даже в этих уроках в редакторе можно было увидеть, что за рендер материала на 3d обьекте отвечает компонент MeshRenderer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я упустил, что компонент `Terrain` сам является рендерером, к которому можно через его игровой объект:

```
terrobj.GetComponent<Terrain>().materialTemplate = material;
```

Таким образом мы можем задать материал для рендеринга суши.

Comment: Однако ещё остаётся открытым вопрос, как организовать использование нескольких материалов. Буду благодарен за более подробный ответ на тему рендеринга суши, в том числе - с ипользованием `MeshRenderer`.

Comment: Наверно, чтобы рисовать, нужно как минимум использовать `Terrain.activeTerrain.terrainData` и там уже через какой-нибудь `GetAlphamaps` и `SetAlphamaps`? Или что вы подразумеваете под ` использование нескольких материалов. `? Не совсем понятно. что требуется, добавить или рисовать по конкретным координатам или рандомно?

Comment: @And имеется в виду кроме карты высот сгенерировать ещё карту почв (это дело техники), а потом применять на терраин различные материалы/текстуры (я пока не очень понял, где пролегает различие между ними) на её основе. На данный момент мне видится, что проще всего это делать с помощью шейдеров, но у меня нулевой опыт их написания.

Comment: [Обязательно к прочтению](http://procworld.blogspot.com/), Вот же и про [Realtime Procedural Terrain Generation](https://web.mit.edu/cesium/Public/terrain.pdf) - довольно хорошо все описано. Ну и на [хабре статейка](https://habr.com/ru/post/226635/). Если хорошо поискать еще найти можно. Все в ваших силах!